# Add a new sms into iPhone inbox programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I searched all already asked questions here on Stack Overflow, and all of them deal with "sending" an SMS programmatically to another phone and that is NOT what I want.

I want to just add an SMS to the inbox, without using the cellular network or any other service and write a from "my_company_name" etc. Basically I want to avoid making the user or my company pay for the SMS. I know about push notifications and I will use them as well, but I need SMSs.

I thought about that maybe, if the user sends the SMS to himself it would be free of charge, but that "seems" to be not true at all.

Comment: First of all, drop the Xcode tag. It has nothing todo with the IDE. I'd also suggest to add the iOS tag. Furthermore, is this about an app for jailbroken devices?

Comment: ok, what you said about the tags makes sense... I have no intention on distributing this app on jailbroken iPhones, only regular app store...
ps. did you vote down my question? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Messages app (and its notification UIs) only displays messages that come in over SMS or iMessage. What you're looking for isn't possible with public API.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no public API available to do this (I guess you already now that), you'll have to go for the private APIs.

You might want to take a look at the source code of BigBoss's [WifiSMS](https://github.com/treason/WifiSMS/tree/master/wifiSMS). This app allows one to control the iPhone's SMS system thru your computer. I haven't tested it myself yet, but BigBoss is a pretty credible application creator when it comes to jailbroken devices.